# grammatical name of this structure: an agreement arrived at through diplomatic conversation

Tags: grammar

I understand the meaning, But I don't know what is the name of these structures in grammar? and I'm not sure if "structure" is the right word for explaining my purpose. Please correct me if there is a better word to describe my question :)

Here is the whole sentence:

> Entente is not a formal treaty but **an agreement arrived at through diplomatic conversation**, which leads to common action and policy.

the "to arrive at an agreement" is the original collocation/structure. But in the new form, we have "the agreement arrived at". What is this structure called?
is it some kind of "inversion"?

Comment: "the "to arrive an agreement" is the original collocation". No, it is not--["to arrive AT an agreement"](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=agreement) is correct.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. That was a typo. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a noun phrase "an agreement", modified by a non-finite clause "arrived at through diplomatic conversation".

The non-finite clause is a participle clause, and it is a passive clause since the grammatical subject "An agreement" is the object of the verb phrase "arrive at".